# Schnorr group membership

Tags: group-theory, cryptography

Consider the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$ (where $p$ is prime). Suppose this has a subgroup of order $q$ (where $q$ is prime). (Such a subgroup is known as [Schnorr group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group).)

Let $0 < x < p$. Why is $x^q \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ sufficient to show that $x$ lies in the given subgroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The multiplicative group of integers modulo a prime, also denoted $\;\Bbb F_p^*\;$, is a cyclic group, just as **any** *finite* subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is.

2) A finite cyclic group has one *unique* subgroup of order any divisor of the group's order.

Thus, modulo $\;p\;$ , we have that

$$\text{For}\;x\neq1\pmod p\;:\;\;\;\;x^q=1\iff \langle x\rangle\;\;\text{has order}\;\;q\;\;in\;\;\Bbb F_p^*\iff$$

$$\iff\langle x\rangle \;\;\text{is THE subgroup of order}\;\;q$$

Comment: A multiplicative group modulo $n$ is *also* also often denoted $U_n$ (because it is the group of units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Indeed so, @user1729. Yet the OP seems to come from cryptography (because of the weird, for me, name "Schnorr"), so I rather wanted to connect it to a field.

Comment: +1, but please add $x \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ in 2)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Further references:

1) [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic)

2) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups)

Comment: Thanx @AndreasCaranti . Done.